# NLog limit the number of times same error is logged within set period

Tags: email, logging, log4net, nlog

We are using NLog to send email messages whenever a 'serious' error occurs. It might be happening very often in some cases generating too many messages.

Is there a way to make NLog limit the number of messages it sends on one particular or any error within a set period?

Is there an analogous mechanism in log4net or any other popular logging library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see my answer to a similar log4net question here:

[log4net - any filter for logging only the Nth message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208541/log4net-any-filter-for-logging-only-the-nth-message/4308493#4308493)

In that answer I proposed a custom log4net Filter implementation that allows repeated messages within a configurable time period to be throttled.

For NLog, the easiest way might be to write a custom Wrapper [target](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Targets).  The custom Wrapper target implemenation would examine the incoming logging messages, forwarding if the current message is different than the most recent message (or maybe if a certain amount of time has passed).  You could then wrap any existing Target with this custom Wrapper.

Note that I have not actually written a Wrapper target, or I would try to provide more info.

Comment: This is what I already did, thank you. Inherited from 'CompoundTargetBase' and overriden 'Write(AsyncLogEventInfo logEvent)'.

Comment: @Den can you please provide more information on how you implemented this, thanks.

Comment: @jaminator - posted as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Config file changes:

```
 <target name="SystemErrorLog" xsi:type="TokenTimeThrottler" EntryExpirationPeriodSec="300">
    <target xsi:type="AsyncWrapper" queueLimit="5000" overflowAction="Discard">
      <target xsi:type="Mail" ... />
    </target>   </target>
```

Target Class:

```
[Target("TokenTimeThrottler", IsCompound = true)]
public class ThrottlingLogTarget : CompoundTargetBase
{
    private ITokenTimeThrottler _tokenTimeThrottler;

    public ThrottlingLogTarget()
        : this(new Target[0])
    {
    }

    public ThrottlingLogTarget(params Target[] targets)
        : base(targets)
    {
    }

    [Required]
    public int EntryExpirationPeriodSec { get; set; }

    protected override void InitializeTarget()
    {
        base.InitializeTarget();

        _tokenTimeThrottler = new TokenTimeThrottler(EntryExpirationPeriodSec > 0 ? EntryExpirationPeriodSec : 0);
    }

    protected override void Write(AsyncLogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        if (this.Targets.Count == 0)
        {
            logEvent.Continuation(null);
            return;
        }

        var token = string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", logEvent.LogEvent.LoggerName, logEvent.LogEvent.Level, logEvent.LogEvent.FormattedMessage);

        if (_tokenTimeThrottler.CheckAllow(token))
        {
            foreach (var target in Targets)
            {
                target.WriteAsyncLogEvent(logEvent);
            }
        }
    }
}


public class TokenTimeThrottler : ITokenTimeThrottler
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, DateTime> _entriesLastTimes;
    private readonly int _expirationPeriodSec;

    public TokenTimeThrottler(int entryExpirationPeriodSec)
    {
        _entriesLastTimes = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, DateTime>();

        _expirationPeriodSec = entryExpirationPeriodSec;
    }

    public bool CheckAllow(string token)
    {
        DateTime lastLoggedTime;

        if (_entriesLastTimes.TryGetValue(token, out lastLoggedTime))
        {
            DateTime? updatedTime = null;

            if (lastLoggedTime.AddSeconds(_expirationPeriodSec) < DateTime.Now)
            {
                updatedTime = DateTime.Now;
            }

            _entriesLastTimes.AddOrUpdate(token, k => updatedTime ?? lastLoggedTime,
                                            (k, v) => updatedTime ?? v);

            return updatedTime.HasValue;
        }

        _entriesLastTimes.AddOrUpdate(token, k => DateTime.Now, (k, v) => v);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Den If its not a huge trouble can you also please mention how you instantiated this class in your code? was it part of the same project? or did you compile this as a dll and reference it in your code as https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/How-to-write-a-Target  suggests ? I am trying to limit file logging using this does appear to be working for me.

Comment: My file log config looks like this:
<target name="SystemErrorLog" xsi:type="TokenTimeThrottler" EntryExpirationPeriodSec="300">
        <target xsi:type="AsyncWrapper" queueLimit="5000" overflowAction="Discard">
          <target name="FileLog" xsi:type="File" layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}${onexception:${exception:format=tostring}}" encoding="iso-8859-2" fileName="c:\git\logs\filer-${shortdate}.log" archiveFileName="c:\git\logs\archives\filer-${shortdate}.{#####}.txt" /> </target> </target>

Comment: @jaminator it was a part of project. If I had more time I would pack it as internal NuGet along with other NLog stuff.

Comment: Den the only thing i want you to comment on is, nesting a file target instead of mail should work?

Comment: <target name="SystemErrorLog" xsi:type="TokenTimeThrottler" EntryExpirationPeriodSec="1">
        <target xsi:type="AsyncWrapper" queueLimit="1" overflowAction="Discard">
          <target xsi:type="File" layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}${onexception:${exception:format=tostring}}" encoding="iso-8859-2" fileName="c:\logs\personprofiler-${shortdate}.log" archiveFileName="c:\logs-${shortdate}.{#####}.txt" archiveNumbering="Sequence" concurrentWrites="true" keepFileOpen="false" />
        </target>
      </target>

Comment: @jaminator did not test, but my expectation is for it to work. It's something like AsyncWrapper in the end of the day. Targets seem to be composable.

Comment: Useful, thanks. One point: it seems you only AddOrUpdate() the ConcurrentDictionary, but never remove from it, creating a memory leak, at least for long running or high volumes; is that fair to say, or am I missing something? One might of course timeout entries in the dictionary when it gets big or entries get old.

Comment: Theoretically you are right, practically it's meant to protect from being spammed about same error every minute. If there are lots of different errors being logged then there is a bigger problem to solve :). If there are few similar errors then it's not a problem. To be perfect I guess it should be cleared regularly as you have suggested. Especially if the server allows executing arbitrary logic and is meant to run for years without rebooting :).