# Filter Log4Net Messages based on number of times a log has occurred

Tags: c#, log4net, config

Is there any way to say in Log4Net, "show me every 5th log from this class that occurs"

I know you can use filters to prevent logs from a certain class from appearing. However I do want to see this log message to know that the code is still running, but it is from a class that logs every 1 second and there can be up to 30 of these classes in existence which means 30 logs a second. I could keep a counter in the code but I want to know if there is a way to do this in a Log4Net config file.

Comment: 30 times a second could be a performance bottleneck, so your best bet may be to reduce the logging frequency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer here to an earlier question that is similar.

[log4net - any filter for logging only the Nth message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208541/log4net-any-filter-for-logging-only-the-nth-message/4308493#4308493)

In the case of the question linked above, the OP wanted to log every Nth message.  My proposed solution was to write a log4net Filter that only lets every Nth message through to the appender.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Writing a filter would be great. I don't think there is any other way through pure xml configuration so this is the next best step and at least the filter could be used in the config if needed.