# How to prevent repeated exception in log4net?

Tags: c#, log4net

Is there a way to prevent log4net to log the same exception n-times?
What I want to achieve is that if the last exception is the same of the actual exception, then I don't want to log.

Comment: How does your logging code look at the moment? A [MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is always great.

Comment: Where is the code? log4net does *not* log the same exception n times - it's the *exception handling code* that does this. If you don't want to log in every method, just don't. Log at the highest point in a call hierarchy, eg in the action of an MVC controller, or the command handler in a WPF application. Or change the severity level of different log calls and apply filters, with the highest severity at the top, lower (verbose, debugging) at lower levels

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208541/log4net-any-filter-for-logging-only-the-nth-message/4308493#4308493)

Comment: @Panagiotis Yeah, I understand that the code itself shoud manage this thing and avoid logging the same message n-times. What I want to know is if log4net already have some filter mechanism to simplify my life :)

Comment: You are looking at it the wrong way. There are no same messages - these are different calls, from different locations even. How would *a human* decide that it's the same message instead of eg, multiple similar exceptions? You can define various filters in the configuration, based on severity, logger, patterns etc. I already mentioned one possibility, log with different severities at different levels and filter on severity.

Answer (score 1):

A buffering appender with a lossy parameter set to true would do the trick if you are ready to write a custom class to plug into it. Here is the code for the appending of an event in the `BufferingAppenderSkeleton`

```
if (this.m_cb == null || this.m_bufferSize <= 1)
{
    if (!this.m_lossy || (this.m_evaluator != null && this.m_evaluator.IsTriggeringEvent(loggingEvent)) || (this.m_lossyEvaluator != null && this.m_lossyEvaluator.IsTriggeringEvent(loggingEvent)))
    {
        if (this.m_eventMustBeFixed)
        {
            loggingEvent.Fix = this.Fix;
        }
        this.SendBuffer(new LoggingEvent[]
        {
            loggingEvent
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see, if you set a buffer size over 1, lossy to true and an evaluator, you can then decide to let an event pass if `this.m_lossyEvaluator.IsTriggeringEvent(loggingEvent)` returns true.

So you can create a custom `ITriggeringEventEvaluator` and let it store the latest exception that passed through, then for each successive exception compare both value. If they are the same return false, if not return true and change the latest exception value.
Then create a `BufferingForwardingAppender` and configure it with your evaluator.

Comment: This answer is purely technical, but the comments on your question should be heeded.