# Similar message filtering based on a template in Log4Net

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

I'm using Log4Net in C# and I want to block multiple writing of same consecutive messages to log.
I have couple of templates and I want to check them against the message by the starting with, also I want to log the first and the last message of the same pattern and in the last message write the number of times the message repeated.
Is Log4Net able to do that?
Thank you all!

Comment: nopes.. you would need to write that in your custom log writer implementation

Comment: Here's an [example filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208541/log4net-any-filter-for-logging-only-the-nth-message/4308493#4308493) which should get you started. If this is too limited you could use a custom appender, or as previous commenter opined, it may be best to do it in your logging code.